# Power BI returning count=1 while the table has 431 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powerbi

I've been using power bi for a couple of days now, i'm reading a table from sql server data source that has 431 rows, and filling up my sheet. The queries on the fields were working correctly and retrieving correct data, however, for some reason now when counting i'm only getting 1, no matter how much filters i put, although when i "Edit query" on the table, i get total of 431 rows, please find attached a screenshot below

[image]

I'm counting "MASTER_REF" from Movements table, field 150 ( result = 1 ), now a screenshot of my table(Movements):

[image]

As the picture shows, i have 431 rows, and I'm trying to get count of "MASTER_REF", but it doesn't seem to work.

Troubleshooting done :

- Refreshing data (FAILED)
- Refreshing table data (FAILED)
- removing data source and importing again (says 431 rows imported) (FAILED)

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: What does your `field 150` column look like? Also, what are all the columns in your visual? (I can't read that script.)

Comment: ILC Triangular is a custom field, where i use a count and an amount, i'm trying to solve the count issue before moving to amount, field 150's query can be viewed on top of the first screenshot

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the evaluation context that you are getting the result of 1. You will not necessarily get the full 431 if your matrix has any fields that filter `Movements`. If you put that measure by itself on a card visual, what number do you get?